# Error uploading PGP key to Google

Tags: pgp

I am uploading the BASE64 encoded key to Google using the instruction [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-audit/auth#uploading_the_public_key) but when I make the post request, I get the following response

```
Content-Type application/xml is not a valid input type
```

I'm posting this:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps='bVFFTkJGQlVwVklCQ0FDL0NKK0VJR0RaeTJGdUJURU5qVnh2dko5Z29YL2lXTjlaZnByQVBDM1hm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"/>
</atom:entry>
```

What's wrong?
This is the same code given on google link , with base64 encoded key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem,which was causing error

I was not setting the header `application/atom+xml`

Also authorization must be done before doing the request,so one more header must be set with request `Authorization: GoogleLogin auth={yourAuthToken}`

HTH